# Resolve Macro Variable in SAS

Tags: variables, macros, sas

I have a question about resolving macro variables in SAS.  I have the following code, which is a simplified version of a much larger block.  For practical reason, I cannot change the structure of the code.

```
%let a = x1 x2 x3;
%let b = y1 y2 y3;
%let c = a b;


%macro test (input);
    %local i;
    %let string_c = %str(&input);
    %do i=1 %to 2;
        %put &%qscan(&string_c, &i);  /* ? */
    %end;
%mend test;

%test(&c);
```

In Step ? above, I would like to resolve a and b as macro variables and have the system print out

```
x1 x2 x3
```

and then

```
y1 y2 y3
```

However, the code above does not reslove a and b as macro variables and the system prints out

```
&a
&b
```

I am wondering if there is any solution to this problem.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
%let a = x1 x2 x3;
%let b = y1 y2 y3;
%let c = a b;

%macro test (input);
    %local i;
    %let string_c =%str(&input);
    %do i=1 %to 2;
        %put %unquote(&&%qscan(&string_c, &i));
    %end;
%mend test;

%test(&c);
```

Comment: Interesting answer.  Can you add some explanation of why this works, particularly why %unquote() is useful here, even if you remove the quoting with %str() and %qscan().  For example, it helps in this simple test case: 
%macro x; x %mend; %let x=1; %put %unquote(&&%x);

Comment: Thank you, Shenglin.  It works!  A follow-up question similar to Quentin's re why it works :)

Comment: Without %unquote, SAS interpret a/b as text plus &, not a macro variable &a /&b, with %unquote, it force to glue & and a/b together and restore normal tokenization of a value.

Comment: Thank you, Shenglin.  I understand that %unquote unmasks all special characters and mnemonic operators for a value during macro execution.  In Step ? above, it seems to work as %unquote(&&"a") in the first loop, which is equivalent to &&a with quotation marks masked.   I am wondering why we need double amper here to make it work.  Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, there is two step for resolve as x1 x2 x3 for %unquote(&&a). Maybe it is easy to be understood by this: %macro test (input);  %local i;
%let string_c =&input; %do i=1 %to 2;%let x=&%scan(&string_c, &i);
%put %unquote(&x); %end;%mend test; %test(&c); Without & before %scan, it only resolve as a/b.

Comment: One does not simply try to understand `%unquote()`.  The macro tokenizer is pretty easily confused, sometimes simple things that should resolve won't do so, and a well-placed `%unquote()` will most likely fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The & trigger is to resolve a name, but you have followed with another macro trigger % instead of a name. So it does nothing.  It is easier to assign the name to a macro variable and then evaluate it.

```
%macro test(list);
  %local i varname value;
  %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list,%str( )));
    %let varname=%scan(&list,&i,%str( ));
    %let value=&&&varname ;
    %put The value of "&varname" is "&value" ;
  %end;
%mend test;
%let a=One ;
%let b=Two ;
%test(a b);
```

Which results in:

```
The value of "a" is "One"
The value of "b" is "Two"
```

Comment: Thank you, Tom.  My problem is that I have to keep the structure of the code for practical, though not reasonable, reasons :).  Therefore, I have to resolve macro variables a and b in the loop.

Comment: So how is that different than the example I posted? It is resolving the macro variables A and B.  It is just SOOOOOOOO much more manageable if you first parse the name from the list into a new macro variable and then use the &&&mvar syntax to resolve the value of the variable named in MVAR.

Comment: Thank you, Tom.  Yes, I agree that it is more manageable if we actually define "a" and "b" in the macro instead of at the very beginning.  However, my hands are completely tight in the code that I am working on since I have to define a and b at the very beginning because of the existing policy...Long live the bureaucracy :)

Comment: No need to define A and B. You should define a local macro variable, say MVAR, that will be assigned the value of the NAME of the macro variable taken from the input list of delimited names. So if that macro variable is named MVAR and &MVAR=A then &&&MVAR will yield the value of A.